# How can I block access to my servlets and jsps in app engine?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, jsp, servlets

I've build a google app engine, to use it as a database for my android app, so I don't want anyone to access my web application after I will upload it. How can I block it? I thought on using a password as parameter, and if the password doesn't match to show an error page, but this is very risky and not sufficient.
Is there another way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a security constraint to web.xml e.g.

```
   <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

You will need to define some authentication mechanism for your client app though so it gets through e.g. use SSL and send login values that way from the Android app.  In that case make sure you open the URL pattern used by your app up via web.xml.

Comment: How can I send the login values of my google account (I guess the admin is the one that uploaded the google app) from the android app?

Comment: I'm not sure you would want your admin username and password on each Android app.  If users have to register for your app then send the users individual username and password via SSL and authenticate using that.  In that case I would make the URL publicly accessible by not enforcing an auth-constraint in web.xml.  However, I would make the URL your app uses SSL - do this via setting the user-data-constraint to CONFIDENTIAL - http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml.html#Secure_URLs

Comment: You are right I thought that leaving my google account details in the source code is not so smart.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you want users of your Android app to be able to access your app, but nobody else. This isn't possible: anything your Android app can generate can be generated independently without your app.

At best, you can embed a secret token in your app and use it to generate signatures for requests, but it will not be difficult for someone to extract that secret and use it directly.

Comment: Yea, I've just watched the source code of fruit ninja a half hour ago haha.. I guess I'll use the password parameter as my "security".. There's nothing much I can do about it..